# Manage Changing Collections

Tags: c#

I have a collection of Tab objects stored in `editor.tabs`.  I am trying to remove every tab from the list except one.  Here is what my code looks like now, and it does not work for obvious reasons:

```
// We need to make a copy of editor.tabs because other foreach fails 
// since CloseTab actually removes tabs from editor.tabs.
// Basically, during the enumeration of a collection, that collection 
// cannot change. So we just iterate over pointers instead.
List<Tab> tempList = new List<Tab>();

foreach (Tab tab in editor.tabs)
{
    tempList.Add(tab);
}

foreach (Tab tab in tempList)
{
    //Close everything but the current tab
    if (tab != editor.currentTab)
    {
        CloseTab(tab);
    }
}
```

`editor.currentTab` is modified within `CloseTab`, so asking if `tab = editor.currentTab` is not the right question to ask.  We want to be asking if tab equals the value of `editor.currentTab` when we first entered this function.

I thought about making a deep copy of `editor.currentTab`, but this feels excessive.

I also tried to compute the hash of `editor.currentTab` when we first enter the function and then compare it to `tab.GetHashCode()`, but that didn't work either.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

EDIT:

And I just realized that the bug is in my CloseTab function!  Oops!

Comment: What are you doing in `CloseTab` method ?

Comment: Two things of importance: editor.currentTab points to a Tab object that lives in editor.tabs.  We remove this Tab object from editor.tabs and then reassign editor.currentTab to a different Tab object within editor.tabs

Comment: So where do you store the reference to the tab you want to keep?  I am having trouble understanding how editor.currentTab gets closed if the condition to close a Tab is if it is not equal to editor.currentTab.

Answer (score 2):

Because `editor.currentTab` changes after every tab close, you should save it outside the loop:

```
    Tab current = editor.currentTab;
    foreach (Tab tab in tempList)
    {
        //Close everything but the current tab
        if (tab != current)
        {
            CloseTab(tab);
        }
    }
```

Also, using Linq you can change all the code that you posted by:

```
editor.tabs.Where(t => t != editor.currentTab).ToList().Foreach(t => CloseTab(t));
```

Comment: This is actually something else that I tried.  But isn't current now just a pointer to editor.currentTab (which also changes inside CloseTab), which gets us nowhere then?

Comment: Can you post `CloseTab(tab)`?

Comment: `isn't current now just a pointer to editor.currentTab` No, I don't think so. `current` points to the "initially current" tab previously pointed to by `editor.currentTab` before calling `CloseTab(tab);`. Did you try this and didn't work?

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM - what is held in current would just be a pointer to editor.currentTab, which would cause it to point to whatever value/reference is in editor.currentTab, even if that value/reference is changed.

Comment: @DarylBehrens so `string s1 = "foo"; string s2 = s1; s1 = "bar";` results in `s2` pointing to `s1` ?!!?! and `s2` equals `bar` ?!!! No I don't think so.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM  That is because string is a special type and has an overloaded '=' operator that makes a deep copy.  Any object created from a class is a true reference type.  Try what you just did, but instead of using string, use an class called MyString, which has a string property. Try the same thing you suggested and you will indeed see that the s2 is now exactly the same thing as s1.

Comment: `StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("foo"); StringBuilder sb2 = sb1; sb1 = new StringBuilder("bar"); Console.WriteLine(sb2.ToString());` prints "foo" not "bar"

Comment: You are not getting the difference between reference type and value type.  Do this on your own to verify.  Make a class called MyString that has one string property called name. In a program go MyString me = new MyString() {name = "daryl"}; Console.WriteLine(me.name); MyString me2 = me;  me2.name = "ahmed";  Console.WriteLine(me.name).  This will show you what a reference type is, since me.name will now be "ahmed".  In a string, or Stringbuilder, the '=' operator is overloaded to work differently.  Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911712/why-strings-behave-like-valuetype

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38495/discussion-between-daryl-behrens-and-ahmed-kraiem)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a basic flaw in the logic of your code in CloseTab(), but without being able to see what that logic is, I can only speculate.

I imagine the Tab you want to keep is know before you go into all the logic of closing tabs.  Once you have a reference to the tab you want to keep, that reference should not be altered in any way, since it is a static idea like "Hey, I have an apple a pear and a banana, and I want to keep the banana", our logic would look like this:

```
FruitBasket basket = new FruitBasket() {new Fruit(apple), new Fruit(orange), new Fruit(banana)};
Fruit current = banana;
foreach (var fruit in basket)
{
   if (fruit != current)
       throw away fruit;
}
```

Nowhere in this are you chaning which fruit you want to keep, because once you decide to keep a fruit, you keep that idea until you are done getting rid of all the others.  For any more help we will need to see the code in CloseTab to understand what reason you could have for changing the editor.currentTab.