# Is the string type stored on the heap or the stack?

Tags: .net, string, heap-memory, primitive-types, stack-memory

Here's what confuses me: in .NET, the `string` type is a class, but its behavior looks like it is a value type!

So is `string` a value type (stack memory) or a reference type (heap memory)?

Comment: Heap with a pointer on the stack or as part of another heap item's set, it is a reference type.

Comment: What @AdamHouldsworth said plus string pool.

Comment: Avoid confusions Reference types goes to heap and valuetypes to stack([not always](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)).

Comment: and what you mean by *but its behavior look like by value* ? Can you explain some of them?

Comment: i meant <b> but its behavior look like value <\b> if we have 2 string variable?
string s1="koko",s2;
s2=s1;
here s2 will have the value of s1 not the memory adress

Comment: Nope [you're wrong](http://ideone.com/2Yk7i9).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why strings behave like ValueType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911712/why-strings-behave-like-valuetype)

Comment: It is a reference type that behaves like a value type in many ways.

Comment: You apparently believe the myth that value types go on the stack. **This is simply false**. Do the ints in an `int[]` go on the stack?  Does the int in `class C { int x; } ` go on the stack? Of course not.  Simply banish this crazy idea from your thoughts altogether, because it makes no sense at all.  **Variables whose lifetimes are known to be short** go on the stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.String` is a reference-type. The value-like behaviour is actually what is called "immutablility", meaning that the object, once created, cannot be changed. All operations which you would expect to mutate the object (e.g. `.ToUpper()`) instead create a new instance.

Mutability is a separate topic from whether something is a reference-type or a value-type. You can have mutable value types (though they're considered a Bad Idea™).

---

To the issue of allocation, the simple answer is that reference types are *normally* allocated on the heap and value types are *normally* allocated on the stack.

In [The Truth About Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-truth-about-value-types), Eric Lippert explains how the CLR makes allocation decisions based more on the lifetime than anything else. Typically these are details that you don't need to worry about, but it's interesting information to have regardless.

Comment: @Oyeme Thanks for letting us know - I've found its new home and updated the link.